# Retrieve back old messages from POP3 server in Thunderbird

Tags: email, email-client, thunderbird, data-recovery

I am using Thunderbird as an email client for a POP3 server. Recently, I formatted my hard disk drive to change the OS from Windows XP to Windows 7. Consequently, I lost all my local emails. I also don't remember whether or not I had the server settings "Leave messages on server Until I delete them". Is it possible to retrieve back those old messages ?

Comment: If they are present on the server, setting up a new account should fetch them as if they were new messages.

Comment: Thanks Tripleee... It worked. As you said, when I correctly set up the new email account, all the messages were automatically fetched from the server. You are a life saver Tripleee. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Manoj,

You need to contact your email hosting provider to see what's possible on their end. Many don't keep permanent copies of emails. Once a customer downloads the email and deletes it, it is gone. Even if they make daily backups, it's possible that than an email arrived during the day and you downloaded it and deleted it before a backup ever happened.

If these messages are very important to you, you may have some hope of extracting them from your hard drive, depending on how the formatting worked. You can study options for [forensics tools](http://www.forensicswiki.org/) or contact a professional data recovery service.

Comment: OMG! looks like I am gonna face a lot of panic situations. Those were official emails. Some of them still need to be followed up :(

Answer (score 0):

As [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) said in the comment, all the messages from server were automatically fetched when I set up  a new Account. Luckily, it looks like I had the "server settings" to " "Leave messages on server Until I delete them". Thanks [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee).

Answer (score 0):

For a POP server, messages must be deleted explicitly by the POP client, though there is possibly a size limit for the server mailbox, in that case older messages will be deleted by the server automatically.

Messages being kept on the server by default, they can be retrieved by more than one POP client (e.g a desktop and a smartphone), provided the appropriate deletion scheme is used.

The client sends the deletion command based on the client parameters. For Thunderbird, these are the options used to manage deletions:

[image]

Once the deletion command has been sent, the message is marked as deleted. Deleted messages can be restored during the same session by a `RSET` command.

The POP session ends when the client sends a `QUIT` command. The session state is switched from `TRANSACTION` to `UPDATE` and messages marked as deleted are removed from the mailbox. After this point the possibilities to restore a deleted message are not part of the protocol, they are fully provider dependent, and may be inexistent.

POP3 (version 3) protocol is described in [RFC 1939](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt).

Note POP is a a text protocol, a mail client is not required, mail can be managed using a simple console, typing appropriate commands and displaying the server responses.

When the message list is retrieved (`LIST`), each message in the list is given a sequential number by the server. The number can be used by the client to get the full message (e.g. `RETR 12`), and/or to delete it (e.g. `DELE 12`).

Instead of using `LIST`, the command `UIDL` can be used, the returned list contains a unique ID for each message. The important point is this ID is persisted between sessions, and uniquely identifies a message. This allows the client to download only new messages.